# Add an active class to a filter link AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have set up my site using AngularJS so the data is looped and displays correctly. I also have a menu on the side that when you click each link will show only that category however I cannot seem to be able to add the active class on each link as they are clicked (and obviously removed when clicked on another category) I either have all the links with active or none. Unfortunately have tried to get this to work on js fiddle but the code that is working for me locally is not working. Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

Js file:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize']);

myApp.factory('Videos', function () {
    var Videos = {};
    Videos.video = [{
        Title: "VIDEO TITLE",
        SubHeading: "SUBTITLE",
        Category: "CATEGORY 1",
        Version: "1",
        url: "asdfghjkl;",
        image: "IMAGE",
        alt: "Image alt",
        description: "Some Text",
        link: "<a href=\"/URL\"><i class='fa-li fa fa-anchor flower'></i>LINK</a>",
        link2: "<a href=\"/URL2\"><i class='fa-li fa fa-anchor flower'></i>LINK2</a>"
    }, {
        Title: "VIDEO TITLE 2",
        SubHeading: "SUBTITLE",
        Category: "CATEGORY 2",
        Version: "1",
        url: "asdfghjkl;",
        image: "IMAGE",
        alt: "Image alt",
        description: "Some Text",
        link: "<a href=\"/URL\"><i class='fa-li fa fa-anchor flower'></i>LINK</a>",
        link2: "<a href=\"/URL2\"><i class='fa-li fa fa-anchor flower'></i>LINK2</a>"
    }, {
        Title: "VIDEO TITLE 3",
        SubHeading: "SUBTITLE",
        Category: "CATEGORY 3",
        Version: "1",
        url: "asdfghjkl;",
        image: "IMAGE",
        alt: "Image alt",
        description: "Some Text",
        link: "<a href=\"/URL\"><i class='fa-li fa fa-anchor flower'></i>LINK</a>",
        link2: "<a href=\"/URL2\"><i class='fa-li fa fa-anchor flower'></i>LINK2</a>"
    }, {
        Title: "VIDEO TITLE 4",
        SubHeading: "SUBTITLE",
        Category: "CATEGORY 1",
        Version: "1",
        url: "asdfghjkl;",
        image: "IMAGE",
        alt: "Image alt",
        description: "Some Text",
        link: "<a href=\"/URL\"><i class='fa-li fa fa-anchor flower'></i>LINK</a>",
        link2: "<a href=\"/URL2\"><i class='fa-li fa fa-anchor flower'></i>LINK2</a>"
    }, {
        Title: "VIDEO TITLE 5",
        SubHeading: "SUBTITLE",
        Category: "CATEGORY 5",
        Version: "1",
        url: "asdfghjkl;",
        image: "IMAGE",
        alt: "Image alt",
        description: "Some Text",
        link: "<a href=\"/URL\"><i class='fa-li fa fa-anchor flower'></i>LINK</a>",
        link2: "<a href=\"/URL2\"><i class='fa-li fa fa-anchor flower'></i>LINK2</a>"
    }, {
        Title: "VIDEO TITLE 6",
        SubHeading: "SUBTITLE",
        Category: "CATEGORY 6",
        Version: "1",
        url: "asdfghjkl;",
        image: "IMAGE",
        alt: "Image alt",
        description: "Some Text",
        link: "<a href=\"/URL\"><i class='fa-li fa fa-anchor flower'></i>LINK</a>",
        link2: "<a href=\"/URL2\"><i class='fa-li fa fa-anchor flower'></i>LINK2</a>"
    }, {
        Title: "VIDEO TITLE 7",
        SubHeading: "SUBTITLE",
        Category: "CATEGORY 7",
        Version: "1",
        url: "asdfghjkl;",
        image: "IMAGE",
        alt: "Image alt",
        description: "Some Text",
        link: "<a href=\"/URL\"><i class='fa-li fa fa-anchor flower'></i>LINK</a>",
        link2: "<a href=\"/URL2\"><i class='fa-li fa fa-anchor flower'></i>LINK2</a>"
    }, {
        Title: "VIDEO TITLE 8",
        SubHeading: "SUBTITLE",
        Category: "CATEGORY 2",
        Version: "1",
        url: "asdfghjkl;",
        image: "IMAGE",
        alt: "Image alt",
        description: "Some Text",
        link: "<a href=\"/URL\"><i class='fa-li fa fa-anchor flower'></i>LINK</a>",
        link2: "<a href=\"/URL2\"><i class='fa-li fa fa-anchor flower'></i>LINK2</a>"
    }, {
        Title: "VIDEO TITLE 9",
        SubHeading: "SUBTITLE",
        Category: "CATEGORY 3",
        Version: "1",
        url: "asdfghjkl;",
        image: "IMAGE",
        alt: "Image alt",
        description: "Some Text",
        link: "<a href=\"/URL\"><i class='fa-li fa fa-anchor flower'></i>LINK</a>",
        link2: "<a href=\"/URL2\"><i class='fa-li fa fa-anchor flower'></i>LINK2</a>"
    }, {
        Title: "VIDEO TITLE 10",
        SubHeading: "SUBTITLE",
        Category: "CATEGORY 4",
        Version: "1",
        url: "asdfghjkl;",
        image: "IMAGE",
        alt: "Image alt",
        description: "Some Text",
        link: "<a href=\"/URL\"><i class='fa-li fa fa-anchor flower'></i>LINK</a>",
        link2: "<a href=\"/URL2\"><i class='fa-li fa fa-anchor flower'></i>LINK2</a>"
    }];
    return Videos;
});

function VideoCtrl($scope, Videos) {
    $scope.filters = {};
    $scope.videos = Videos;
}
```

HTML:

```
        <h1 class="pageheading">
            PAGE TITLE  </h1>
            <hr class="heading" />
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12" ng-controller="VideoCtrl">
                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-9" >
                            <div class="media thumbnail software" itemprop="video" ng-repeat="video in videos.video | filter:filters" >
                                <div class="col-md-5 text-center'" ng-class-even="'col-md-push-7'">
                                    <div class="play-container">

                                        <a ngHref="http://youtu.be/{{video.url}}?autoplay=1" class="fancybox-media picimg">
                                            <img alt="{{video.alt}}" ng-src="assets/img/{{video.image}}.jpg">

        <span class="play-control">
            <span class="fa fa-play-circle hidden-xs"></span>
        </span>
    </a>            
</div>
</div>
<div class="media-body col-md-7" ng-class-odd="'blue'" ng-class-even="'col-md-pull-5 green'">
<h2 class="media-heading pageheading">
        <a ngHref="http://youtu.be/{{video.url}}?autoplay=1" class="fancybox-media" itemprop="embedUrl">
        <span itemprop="name" ng-bind-html="video.Title"></span>
        </a>        
        </h2>
        <h3 ng-bind-html="video.SubHeading"></h3>
        <small><i ng-bind-html="video.Version">{{video.Version}}</i></small>
        <hr class="heading">
        <p itemprop="description" ng-bind-html="video.description"></p>
        <ul class="fa-ul">
            <li ng-bind-html="video.link">{{video.link}}</li>
            <li><a ng-click="filters.Category = video.Category">{{video.Category}}</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

</div>
<br class="visible-xs" />
<div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3 software">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">
                <i class="fa fa-video-camera"></i> Video Categories     </h3>
            </div>

            <nav class="list-group">
                <a href ng-click="filters.Category = 'Category 1'" class="list-group-item" >Category 1<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
                <a href ng-click="filters.Category = 'Category 2'" class="list-group-item">Category 2 <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
                <a href ng-click="filters.Category = 'Category 3'" class="list-group-item">Category 3 <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
                <a href ng-click="filters.Category = 'Category 4'" class="list-group-item">Category 4 <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
                <a href ng-click="filters.Category = 'Category 5'" class="list-group-item">Category 5 <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
                <a href ng-click="filters.Category = 'Category 6'" class="list-group-item">Category 6 <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
                <a href ng-click="filters.Category = 'Category 7'" class="list-group-item">Category 7 <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>   </nav>
            </div>              </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As far as I can work out I need to add something like ng-class="{ active: clicked }" to each link but am unsure how to proceed on the js side as each example I have seen is either way more complex or much simpler. So basically I want when I click on Category 1 only the items that are in Category 1 are showing (which is working) and also the link for Category 1 to have an active class applied.

After that I would like to be able at the same time to change the page title to change to a heading specified for each Category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the fact that the currently selected category is on the scope.

```
ng-class="{active: filters.Category == 'Category 1'}"
```

Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/vcuJECCSM7KHJaU9eZKq?p=preview

Comment: Thanks a lot simpler than I thought :)

Comment: I want to go 1 step further with this is there another easy way so that when the page loads it starts with the filter on Category 1. Every time I try I can see Cat 1 but none of the links then work (obviously would need the category 1 link to also default to having the active class)

Comment: solved I think added: data-ng-init="filters.Category = 'Category 1'" to the first link